# Host TimeLineJS on Meteor app without smart package

Tags: meteor, dependency-injection, dependency-management, timeline.js

I'd like to host the [TimeLineJS](https://github.com/NUKnightLab/TimelineJS) library on my Meteor app locally and not use the smart package because I need to fine tune it. I've tried declaring the createStoryJS function in the Meteor space like [this](https://github.com/NUKnightLab/TimelineJS/blob/master/build/js/timeline.js) in create Timeline.js. However, there are other dependencies (storyjs-embed.js, storyjs-embed-generator.js, storyjs-embed.js, and everything under locale) which rely on the document object on the browser. How can I ensure that Timeline.js is loaded in a template with all of its dependencies locally managed, while successfully accessing the window.document object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put all the files in `client/compatibility` in your app, such that the dependencies load first via Meteor’s [load order](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/structuringyourapp) (e.g. put dependencies in `client/compatibility/lib`, for example). That’s all you have to do: no `script` tags, no declaring anything. Initialize TimeLineJS within a template’s `onRendered` callback.